Does TypeORM Replication support failover in case where source DB fails?
I am trying to set up a db replication in MySQL with TypeORM. I want to know if TypeORM replication configuration also supports failover, i.e, if replica DB will be promoted as source DB while source is down, or the configuration is just about replication and facilitates no functionality over failover? Here's my datasource connection.
{
  type: 'mysql',
  migrations: ['dist/db/migrations/deviceDB/*.js'],
  entities: ['dist/src/model/device/**/**/*.entity.js'],
  name: 'device',
  
// logging: process.env.DEVICE_DB_LOGGING == 'TRUE' ? true : false,
  logging: 'all',
  dateStrings: true,
  replication: {
    master: {
      port: 3306,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      database: 'DEVICE',
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    },
    slaves: [
      {
        port: 3306,
        host: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_HOST,
      username: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_USERNAME,
      database: 'DEVICE',
      password: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_PASSWORD,
      },
    ],
  },
  extra: {
    connectionLimit: 1000,
  },
}

Replication is working fine, but I just want to know if TypeORM replication config supports failover or not. Because, everytime I bring a master down to test the failover, there's an error saying 'pool does not exists'. So I suspect, may be replication config is just about replication.
